# Just implement some properties in interface

Tags: c#

I have a interface with some properties:

```
public interface Test
{
    string GetName();
    string GetLastName();
    string GetFullName();
}
```

and I have a A and B class implement the interface Test. But in class A, I just want to implement GetName() and GetLastName() methods. And class B just implement GetFullName(). Could I do it?. Because I want to implement what I need for each specific class.

Comment: Then what's the point of a common interface?

Comment: Exactly - then you should have two separate interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot skip implementing some members of interface. If class implements interface, then you should provide full implementation.

But if some client does not need all properties of interface, then split this interface on smaller interfaces. That is called Interface Segregation Principle.

```
public interface TestA
{
    string GetName();
    string GetLastName();
}

public interface TestB
{
    string GetFullName();
}

public interface Test : TestA, TestB
{        
}
```

Implement `TestA` interface by class A, and `TestB` by class B. If none class needs full interface `Test` then just remove it.

Comment: It doesn't fit. Class A have to implement TestA only and B `GetFullName`. In your case, class B have to implement all methods.

Comment: @pwas thnaks, I was in the middle of typing full sample

Comment: Ok, so then save you post after it is finished (not in the middle) - otherwise it introduces a little mess :)

Comment: ok, strange pratice (especcially that lots of people can see and read uncompleted answer) - but if all do this.. :)

Comment: @pwas btw I didn't write that class B should implement interface Test in first edit of answer :) I just wrote sample of TestA interface. And added another sample of TestB interface later. And yes, its OK to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have two split the interface to another two interfaces. Then the `classA` would implement the one interface and the `classB` the second. This is the so called *Interface Segregation Prinicple*, according to which:

> no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use

for more information about this principle, please have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

By the way is one of the five principles in [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))